# How can I export from Excel file to a csv file, where the file has leading zeros, in text format?

Tags: excel, vba, csv

I have this code:

```vb
Sub GravarArquivoCSV()

Open Range("E1").Value For Output As 1

Sheets("APR_CSV").Activate
Range("A1").Select

Do While ActiveCell.Text <> ""
    Print #1, ActiveCell.Value & ";" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value & ";" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 3).Value & ";" & Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 4).Value
    Cells(ActiveCell.Row + 1, ActiveCell.Column).Select
Loop

MsgBox "Arquivo gerado com sucesso!", vbInformation, "OK"
Close 1

Sheets("Autoline Controlo Compras").Activate
End Sub
```

But all the info became without left zeros in the output csv generated:

Intended:

```
62013227 001148160R 1 41563 M02-UL-98
62013227 8200212598 2 42426 M25-BI-26
62013227 0000066444 1 42490 C19-RA-68
62013227 8200725845 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227 7701475837 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227 0000474796 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227 8200661217 2 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
```

CSV Export: Without the needed left ZERO 000

```
62013227 001148160R 1 41563 M02-UL-98
62013227 8200212598 2 42426 M25-BI-26
62013227 66444 1 42490 C19-RA-68
62013227 8200725845 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227 7701475837 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227 474796 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227 8200661217 2 43858 BJ1 0028 11485
```

How can I have the leading zeroes?

Comment: `Format(Cells(ActiveCell.Row, 2).Value, "0000000000")`.

Comment: But the firt line of the csv is with the needed zero in the lenght, after de second row the vba code seems to remove the zeros !

Comment: You export with ";" as divider, but your example shows blanks instead. Are the leading zeros missed directly in the CSV-file or only after reopening the CSV with Excel?

Comment: The leading zeros are missed in the csv opened iin excel, but the original file as the leading zeros before export to the csv, the first row is ok you can see the leading zeros, but from de second one the error exists!

Comment: Open in NotePad = All OK
62013227;001148160R;1;41563 M02-UL-98
62013227;8200212598;2;42426 M25-BI-26
62013227;0000066444;1;42490 C19-RA-68
62013227;8200725845;1;43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227;7701475837;1;43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227;0000474796;1;43858 BJ1 0028 11485
62013227;8200661217;2;43858 BJ1 0028 11485

open in csv via excel = No leading zeros from the second row!

Answer (score 2):

### Export

If you need leading zeros, then [Format](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/format-function-visual-basic-for-applications) should help.

You should also [avoid selecting or activating anything](https://stackoverflow.com/q/10714251/10908769).
Therefore I used a variable "i" for a loop over all rows.

As filenumber 1 may already be in use, it is better to use `FreeFile`.

```
Sub GravarArquivoCSV()
    Dim fileNum As Long
    Dim i As Long

    fileNum = FreeFile
    Open Range("E1").Value For Output As fileNum

    With Sheets("APR_CSV")
        i = 1
        Do While .Cells(i, "A").Text <> ""
            Print #FileNum, .Cells(i, "A").Value & ";" & _
                      Format(.Cells(i, "B").Value, "0000000000") & ";" & _
                      .Cells(i, "C").Value & ";" & _
                      .Cells(i, "D").Value
            i = i + 1
        Loop
    End With
    Close fileNum

    MsgBox "Arquivo gerado com sucesso!", vbInformation, "OK"
    Sheets("Autoline Controlo Compras").Activate
End Sub
```

---

### Import

When you import this CSV into Excel, Excel recognises the numbers as numbers.
Therefore you have two options:

- keep it as number and give it a customized number format,
  e. g. "0000000000" shows numbers with leading zeros
- import it as text string by following VBA code

Please adapt the filepath and filename to your needs.

```
Public Sub ImportCSV()
    Dim wb As Workbook
    Set wb = Application.Workbooks.Add

    With wb.Worksheets(1).QueryTables.Add( _
        Connection:="TEXT;" & Application.DefaultFilePath & "\APR_CSV.csv", _
        Destination:=wb.Worksheets(1).Range("A1"))
        .Name = "APR_CSV"
        .FieldNames = False
        .RowNumbers = False
        .FillAdjacentFormulas = False
        .PreserveFormatting = True
        .RefreshOnFileOpen = False
        .RefreshStyle = XlCellInsertionMode.xlInsertDeleteCells
        .SavePassword = False
        .SaveData = True
        .AdjustColumnWidth = True
        .RefreshPeriod = 0
        .TextFilePromptOnRefresh = False
        .TextFilePlatform = XlPlatform.xlWindows
        .TextFileStartRow = 1
        .TextFileParseType = XlTextParsingType.xlDelimited
        .TextFileTextQualifier = XlTextQualifier.xlTextQualifierNone
        .TextFileConsecutiveDelimiter = False
        .TextFileTabDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSemicolonDelimiter = True
        .TextFileCommaDelimiter = False
        .TextFileSpaceDelimiter = False
        .TextFileColumnDataTypes = Array( _
            XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat, _
            XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat, _
            XlColumnDataType.xlGeneralFormat, _
            XlColumnDataType.xlTextFormat)
        .TextFileDecimalSeparator = "."
        .TextFileThousandsSeparator = ","
        .TextFileTrailingMinusNumbers = True
        .Refresh BackgroundQuery:=False
        .Delete
    End With
End Sub
```

---

### Path of the Excel file

Please either use the `ActiveWorkbook`, which is the currently active file, or `ThisWorkbook`, which is the file with your VBA code. They are the same, if the file containing your VBA code also is the active file.

Use its `Path`, add a backslash "\" and add the desired CSV filename (e. g. "APR CSV Renault.CSV").

Experiment with his:

```
Private Sub DebugMyPaths
' always the file with THIS VBA code:
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.Path & "\" & ThisWorkbook.Name
Debug.Print ThisWorkbook.FullName

' always the active Excel file:
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\" & ActiveWorkbook.Name
Debug.Print ActiveWorkbook.FullName
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, but not always the reference as the same lenght ( 0000000000 ), can you help me, i'm new to VBA.

The result is the same, only the first row as the leading zeros!!

62013227 001148160R 1 41563 M02-UL-98

62013227 8200212598 2 42426 M25-BI-26

62013227 66444 1 42490 C19-RA-68

62013227 8200725845 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485

62013227 7701475837 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485

62013227 474796 1 43858 BJ1 0028 11485

62013227 8200661217 2 43858 BJ1 0028 11485

Comment: Open in NotePad = All OK 62013227;001148160R;1;41563 M02-UL-98 62013227;8200212598;2;42426 M25-BI-26 62013227;0000066444;1;42490 C19-RA-68 62013227;8200725845;1;43858 BJ1 0028 11485 62013227;7701475837;1;43858 BJ1 0028 11485 62013227;0000474796;1;43858 BJ1 0028 11485 62013227;8200661217;2;43858 BJ1 0028 11485 open in csv via excel = No leading zeros from the second row!

Comment: I have this vba code in excel, but i need to make some changes so that the file can be used by anyone, in this case the vba code is only for my folder/PC.


 FileNum = FreeFile
 Open Range("E1").Value For Output As fileNum

Where:  Cell E1 contains c:\users\xx\xx\APR CSV Renault.CSV

How can I have the vba code to output the .csv to the same path of the .xls file for any that as this file in is PC ?

Comment: Sorry to ask, but where do i feet the code, i'm new in vba to export?

Comment: `Open ActiveWorkbook.Path & "\Whatever.csv" For Output As FileNum`

Comment: In the Export language how can I export to a .txt file witg tab delimited layout ?

Comment: Then you get a tab-delimited textfile by just replacing all `";"` by `Chr(9)`. This works independent of the file extension, which may be .csv oder .txt.